# How do I know which product IOS my router has

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-xr

All

My device ASR-1001-X

I'm trying to see what type of product my IOS is on my router. As I'm buying another one of the same kind. My current router has this information

```
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 16.09.02
Cisco IOS Software [Fuji], ASR1000 Software (X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 16.9.2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc4)



License Type: Smart License
License Level: ipbase
Next reload license Level: ipbase
```

The website that I'm buying this new router has one of the configurations.

SASR1K1XU-313S   =>   Cisco ASR1001-X IOS XE UNIVERSAL – NO ENCRYPTION

So My question is, how do I find that product ID "SASR1K1XU-313S" if possible in my current routers CLI.

If I do buy that new router, could I change the IOS, or are there features that will help get the traffic encrypted. I'm Based in the U.S, so cryptography export laws don't apply to me.

Thanks, ahead of time.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below commands,

```
show version
show tech info
show inventory
```

`show tech info` will take long time to load because it will show all technical specifications and many other details as well.

You don't need to think about router if you are going to receive encryption traffic. But if you want to generate traffic with additional security you need to purchase device which has expected facility.

Answer (score 5):

This is the IOS version Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 16.09.02

the command "show inventory" will show you the hardware part numbers, serial number, and version

Answer (score 3):

> So My question is, how do I find that product ID "SASR1K1XU-313S" if possible in my current routers CLI.

You likely won't. This is simply a software license component that is only one part of what you need.

To illustrate, here is one of a number of examples of the type of "parts list" you will generate when ordering such a router from [Cisco's ASR 1000 Series ordering guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/asr-1000-series-aggregation-services-routers/guide-c07-731639.html#_Toc7831143) (login required):

[image]

If you don't have access to a Cisco login, then you can at least get some idea from the [ASR 1000 Datasheet "Ordering Information" section](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/asr-1000-series-aggregation-services-routers/datasheet-c78-731632.html#OrderingInformation).

Note that this type of parts list provides for things like the chassis, any additional processor modules, power supplies, and various software licenses specific to the purpose the device is going to be used for when deployed.

Some of this you will be able to change after ordering (typically at additional costs), but it is generally better to order what you need as part of one initial order (often you best pricing this way).

If you are unfamiliar with the process and don't have access to the Cisco documentation/tools for ordering devices like this (or a Cisco sales contact), I highly recommend you work with a Cisco partner to make this purchase. They should be able to help you identify what you need and if you provide them with specific specifications/guidance and what they order doesn't meet your needs, you will have someone to hold responsible. They may also know of or be able to find out about Cisco deals that may work to your advantage.